# ndk-build arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've spent all day and have looked at several tutorials, but I cannot get ndk-build to compile my make file.  To see what my current code is, look at the tutorial that I'm following here: https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1153/introduction_to_ndk

I'm on a Windows 7 64-bit system so I'm running Cygwin.  I go to the project directory "FibonacciNative" and type "ndk-build" and this is what I'm getting:

```
$ ndk-build
make: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows-/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
make: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows-/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
Compile thumb  : com_marakana_android_fibonaccinative_FibLib <= com_marakana_android_fibonaccinative_FibLib.c
/bin/sh: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows-/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8/build/core/build-binary.mk:240: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/objs/com_marakana_android_fibonaccinative_FibLib/com_marakana_android_fibonaccinative_FibLib.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/com_marakana_android_fibonaccinative_FibLib/com_marakana_android_fibonaccinative_FibLib.o] Error 127
```

I always get "Command not found."  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Matt

Folders where stuff is installed:
C:\Android\android-ndk-r8
C:\Android\android-sdk
C:!Personal\eclipse/FibonacciNative
C:\cygwin

In Cygwin I have gcc-core, gcc-mingw-core, libgcc1.
Am I perhaps missing something from Cygwin?

Comment: Speculation, but do you have an appropriate version of *make* installed?  What happens if you type '*make --version*' into a cygwin shell?

Comment: $ make --version
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-cygwin

Comment: This bothers me: /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows-/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc in that I suspect there should be something after the windows- before the bin.  Can you look in /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/ and see what the actual subdirectories are?  ndk-build is a script that is probably trying to derive that, it may be getting confused, so you could fix it, or help it with a strategic symlink from what it should be asking for to what it is asking for.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that might be the problem.  I ran ndk-build with logging and saw this: "Android NDK: HOST_TAG set to windows-"Someone here "http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.ndk/16056" had the same problem.  It doesn't look like they fixed it yet either.

Comment: ndk-build is a script you can edit.  Valid values can be determined by what directories exist, pick the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in the script.  I hard-coded HOST_TAG to windows in \build\core\init.mk and it all works just fine.  +1 to Chris Stratton for the help.

```
# If we are on Windows, we need to check that we are not running
# Cygwin 1.5, which is deprecated and won't run our toolchain
# binaries properly.
#
ifeq ($(HOST_TAG),windows-x86)
    ifeq ($(HOST_OS),cygwin)
        # On cygwin, 'uname -r' returns something like 1.5.23(0.225/5/3)
        # We recognize 1.5. as the prefix to look for then.
        CYGWIN_VERSION := $(shell uname -r)
        ifneq ($(filter XX1.5.%,XX$(CYGWIN_VERSION)),)
            $(call __ndk_info,You seem to be running Cygwin 1.5, which is not supported.)
            $(call __ndk_info,Please upgrade to Cygwin 1.7 or higher.)
            $(call __ndk_error,Aborting.)
        endif
    endif
    # special-case the host-tag
    HOST_TAG := windows
endif

HOST_TAG := windows
```

I found it by searching for the misspelling in the message after it "Host tols prebuilt directory not found" :)